# Ternjs plugin is not working as expected

Tags: filetype-javascript, plugin-ternjs

I installed [ternjs_for_vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim) plugin but can't figure out how to use it properly. RTFM didn't help. What I get is list random JS-methods in the omni-completion. But things like completing for Node.JS modules doesn't work. For example if I type:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.
```

and after `.` there is no relevant completion (like methods `readFile`, `readFileSync` etc.)

Here is my .tern-project file:

```
{
    "libs": [
        "underscore",
        "jquery"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "node": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for removing the duplicate submission on SO! (You can still post there in a few days if there's no progress here, though this beta site gets quite some attention in the moment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there was a problem in my .vimrc config.
A long time ago I created some settings regarding Omni completion and forgot about them. So I just deleted this lines from my config:

```
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete
```

and everything works like a charm now.

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually define those autocmds.  If you add `filetype plugin on` to your vimrc, then they should be automatically set.

Comment: @jamessan Yes, It is my very old config and there was some junk in it from that time when I started to learn vim. Hope my config without any issues anymore. Thank you for pointing on this.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states (emphasis added):

> In JavaScript files, the package will hook into **omni completion** to handle autocompletion

[Omni completion](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version7.txt.html#new-omni-completion) doesn't automatically get triggered.  It has to be manually invoked using the key sequence `<C-x><C-o>` in insert mode.  Then you can use [various keys](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#popupmenu-keys) to navigate the resulting completion menu and select the completion you want.  For example, `<C-y>` will accept the completion and `<C-e>` aborts the completion leaving you with the original text.

Comment: I asked about other thing. Omni completion worked fine at that moment. But content of popup window was almost useless.